# Local max and local min

Tags: calculus

If we have a function $f(x)$ with a derivative which changes sign infinitely many times when $x$ approaches zero and $f'(x)=0$ when $x=0$, why can't $x=0$  be a local max or local min?

For example, $f(x)=x^4sin(\frac{1}{x})$ when $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$.
For this function, we know that $x=0$ is a critical number and $f'(x)$ changes sign infinitely many times when $x$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are examples where $x=0$ can still be a local minima despite your given conditions. Recall:

> If $f(x)$ is a function and $a$ an element of its domain, we say that $a$ is a 
>   *local minima* of $f(x)$ if there exists a neighbourhood $U \ni a$ such that $f(a) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in U$.

We will need to modify your function somewhat to see that this is the case. Consider 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x = 0 \\ \max\{x^4\sin(1/x),0\} & x \neq 0 \end{cases}.$$
By Squeeze Theorem, everything you want is true: $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable at $0$ and $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$. As $f(x)$ is always non-negative, $x=0$ is a global (and hence local) minima.

Edit: For a function with continuous derivative, take a look at
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^4\left( \sin\left(\frac1x\right) + e^x\right) & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x =0 \end{cases}.$$
For $x \geq 0$ this function is always non-negative, and again by Squeeze Theorem, everything you want is true.

Comment: I think I got it,thank you

Comment: Your example fails because the function itself switches signs infinitely often in any neighbourhood about zero. The point is that there are counterexamples to your claim. Also, I have edited the above solution to give an example with continuous derivative, in case that is bugging you.